# Displaying number of PWD(y-axis) in every purok(x-axis)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, column-chart

[Desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx2V8.png)

[Current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPgUT.png)

Hey guys, Im trying to make a column chart using the purok and status column. How can you show the PWD and Pregnant as a bar with label and count also? thankyou in advance

> The table name is PWDPregnant | columnName "status" is for PWD/Pregnant. | columnName "purok" is for Pepsi/Coke.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
            Using pwdcon As New OleDbConnection(con.ConnectionString),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT purok, status, COUNT(*) As RecCount FROM PWDPregnant GROUP BY purok, status  ORDER BY purok", con)


                If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    con.Open()
                End If
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(reader)
                End Using
            End Using

            Chart5.Series("PWD").XValueMember = "purok"
            Chart5.Series("PWD").YValueMembers = "status"
            Chart5.Series("PWD").Label = "#AXISLABEL #VALY"


            Chart5.Series("Pregnant").YValueMembers = "status"
            Chart5.Series("Pregnant").Label = "#AXISLABEL #VALY"

            Chart5.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
            Chart5.DataBind()
```

Comment: Trying how? Why is vb.net in question title? How is vb.net involved in designing chart in Access? Do you have code that builds chart?

Comment: Hey I hope the title is clearer now. Somebody help me :<

Comment: Sorry, I don't know vb.net programming that well. I could easily build this chart in Access or Excel without coding.

Comment: Thanks, I already fixed it after hours of debugging and research lol

Comment: When I built this chart in Access, I used a CROSSTAB query for the chart RowSource. It produced the desired chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the fix but it still cant support the 2nd series which is Pregnant.

```
                Dim dt As New DataTable
            Using pwdcon As New OleDbConnection(con.ConnectionString),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT purok, status, COUNT (*) as RecCount FROM PWDPregnant WHERE status = @stat GROUP BY purok, status", con)
              

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stat", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "PWD"



                If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    con.Open()
                End If

            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
            End Using




            Chart5.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
            Chart5.Series("PWD").XValueMember = "purok"
            Chart5.Series("PWD").YValueMembers = "RecCount"
            Chart5.Series("PWD").Label = "#VALY"

            Chart5.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
            Chart5.DataBind()
```